Flask, error: failed to find flask application or factory in module 'app'
I am running Python 3.12.6 on Arch Linux. While running a Flask app, I encountered this error.
(.venv) archlinux% export FLASK_APP=app.py
(.venv) archlinux% export FLASK_ENV=development
(.venv) archlinux% flask run
Usage: flask run \[OPTIONS\]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'. Use 'app:name' to specify one.
(.venv) archlinux%

I have tried running it without flask:
(.venv) archlinux% python app.py
(.venv) archlinux%

But nothing happens.
app.py looks like this
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()


This is what the project directory looks like.
To-do app
    ├── app.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── app.cpython-312.pyc
    │   └── main.cpython-312.pyc
    ├── static
    └── templates
        └── index.html


Note: I am using a virtual environment. It was created using VS Code.

From where are you doing flask run, is it in the same directory as the app.py file?

@GinoMempin i am running it from the venv in the same directory asthe app.py file

Is the name of your outer directory also "app", such that your Flask app is in "app/app.py"?

How about exporting the env var and calling flask CLI all in one command, like: FLASK_APP=app.py python -m flask run or more explicitly FLASK_APP=app:app python -m flask run (still running it from the same directory and with the venv activated)

@GinoMempin doesnt work. how do i provide the terminal output with correct formatting here?

Run cat app.py does the output match the content of your file? Also test running flask after deleting the __pycache__ directory.
